# Combine inter-dependent selected dropdown options to a string

Tags: javascript

I've got three dropdowns that are linked together dynamically so that they update automatically depending on respective selections - i.e. these selected options can change without being clicked on. I'd like to create a variable that would combine the content of the three selected dropdown options into a string.

The expected output should throw a string like "year/month/week" (e.g, "2018/January/week1").

Here's the JSFiddle link:
https://jsfiddle.net/ssoj_tellig/zo85r30x/18/

```js
const my dates = {
  "2018": {
    "January": ["week1", "week2", "week3", "week4"],
    "February": ["week5", "week6", "week7"],
    "March": ["week8", "week9", "week11"]
  },
  "2019": {
    "January": ["week1", "week2", "week3", "week4"],
    "February": ["week5", "week6", "week7"],
    "March": ["week8", "week10", "week11"]
  },
  "2020": {
    "January": ["week1", "week2", "week3", "week4"],
    "February": ["week5", "week6", "week7"],
    "March": ["week8"]
  }
};


const years = Object.keys(mydates);
const initalMonths = Object.keys(Object.values(mydates)[0]);
const initialWeeks = mydates[Object.keys(mydates)[0]][initalMonths[0]];

const $yearSelectionOBJ = document.getElementById('year');
const $monthSelectionOBJ = document.getElementById('month');
const $weekSelectionOBJ = document.getElementById('week');

for (year of years) {
  const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

  $optOBJ.innerHTML = year;
  $yearSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
}

for (month of initalMonths) {
  const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

  $optOBJ.innerHTML = month;
  $monthSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
}

for (week of initialWeeks) {
  const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

  $optOBJ.innerHTML = week;
  $weekSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
}

$yearSelectionOBJ.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  $monthSelectionOBJ.innerHTML = '';
  $weekSelectionOBJ.innerHTML = '';

  for (month in mydates[event.target.value]) {
    const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

    $optOBJ.innerHTML = month;
    $monthSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
  }

  for (week of mydates[event.target.value][Object.keys(mydates[event.target.value])[0]]) {
    const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

    $optOBJ.innerHTML = week;
    $weekSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
  }
});

$monthSelectionOBJ.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  $weekSelectionOBJ.innerHTML = '';

  for (week of mydates[$yearSelectionOBJ.value][$monthSelectionOBJ.value]) {
    const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

    $optOBJ.innerHTML = week;
    $weekSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
  }
});

const selectedyear = document.querySelector(`[id="year"]`);
const selectedmonth = document.querySelector(`[id="month"]`);
const selectedweek = document.querySelector(`[id="week"]`);

selectedweek.addEventListener(`change`, (e) => {
  var select = e.target;
  var desc = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(desc);
});

selectedmonth.addEventListener(`change`, (e) => {
  var select2 = e.target;
  var desc2 = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(desc2);
});

selectedyear.addEventListener(`change`, (e) => {
  var select3 = e.target;
  var desc3 = select3.options[select3.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(desc3);
});
```

```html
<html>

<head></head>

<body>
  <select id="year"></select>
  <select id="month"></select>
  <select id="week"></select>
</body>

</html>
```

Many thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am just answering what I understood from your explanation . so If I got wrong of you than i hope you will give detail explanation in comment  .

here is html code

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <select id="year" onchange="myFunction(event)"></select>
    <select id="month" ></select>
    <select id="week" ></select>
    <input type="text" id="output" />
</body>
</html>
```

and your javascript code goes here

```
const mydates = {
    "2018": {
        "January": ["week1","week2","week3","week4"],
        "February": ["week5","week6","week7"],
        "March": ["week8","week9","week11"]
    },
    "2019": {
        "January": ["week1","week2","week3","week4"],
        "February": ["week5","week6","week7"],
        "March": ["week8","week10","week11"]
    },
    "2020": {
        "January": ["week1","week2","week3","week4"],
        "February": ["week5","week6","week7"],
        "March": ["week8"]
    }
};


const years = Object.keys(mydates);
const initalMonths = Object.keys(Object.values(mydates)[0]);
const initialWeeks = mydates[Object.keys(mydates)[0]][initalMonths[0]];

const $yearSelectionOBJ = document.getElementById('year');
const $monthSelectionOBJ = document.getElementById('month');
const $weekSelectionOBJ = document.getElementById('week');

for (year of years) {
  const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

  $optOBJ.innerHTML = year;
  $yearSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
}

for (month of initalMonths) {
  const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

  $optOBJ.innerHTML = month;
  $monthSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
}

for (week of initialWeeks) {
  const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

  $optOBJ.innerHTML = week;
  $weekSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
}

$yearSelectionOBJ.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  $monthSelectionOBJ.innerHTML = '';
  $weekSelectionOBJ.innerHTML = '';

  for (month in mydates[event.target.value]) {
    const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

    $optOBJ.innerHTML = month;
    $monthSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
  }

  for (week of mydates[event.target.value][Object.keys(mydates[event.target.value])[0]]) {
    const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

    $optOBJ.innerHTML = week;
    $weekSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
  }
});

$monthSelectionOBJ.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
  $weekSelectionOBJ.innerHTML = '';

  for (week of mydates[$yearSelectionOBJ.value][$monthSelectionOBJ.value]) {
    const $optOBJ = document.createElement('option');

    $optOBJ.innerHTML = week;
    $weekSelectionOBJ.appendChild($optOBJ);
  }
});

const selectedyear = document.querySelector(`[id="year"]`);
const selectedmonth = document.querySelector(`[id="month"]`);
const selectedweek = document.querySelector(`[id="week"]`);

selectedweek.addEventListener(`change`, (e) => {
  var select = e.target;
  var desc = select.options[select.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(desc);
});

selectedmonth.addEventListener(`change`, (e) => {
  var select2 = e.target;
  var desc2 = select2.options[select2.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(desc2);
});

selectedyear.addEventListener(`change`, (e) => {
  var select3 = e.target;
  var desc3 = select3.options[select3.selectedIndex].text;
  console.log(desc3);
});
function myFunction(e) {
    document.getElementById("output").value = e.target.value + "/" + document.getElementById("month").value + "/" + document.getElementById("week").value
    
}
// the selected option for the 3 dropdowns should be combined 
// to form a string (part of a local file path),
// expected output example:
// "2018/January/week1"

// Note: selected options can be modified by default
// and do not necessarilly have to be clicked on to be changed
```